# How do i move data from one column to another on values that aren't equal in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in one data frame 'first name' and 'preferred name'. If the preferred name is different to first name, I want to move that value to first name. e.g.:

```
   First Name  Preferred Name  
1  David       Dave       
2  John        John        
3  Sarah       Sarah
4  Elizabeth   Liz



   First Name  Preferred Name  
1  Dave        Dave       
2  John        John        
3  Sarah       Sarah
4  Liz         Liz
```

Comment: Can't you just do `df['First Name'] = df['Preferred Name']`?, also data-wise doesn't this make preferred name/first name redundant here?

Comment: I have over 2000 names, so was looking for a nice way to do it. if not, i will just write a function. the 'preferred name' column came from another table through a join, which I will drop after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest is only assign as pointed [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319855/how-do-i-move-data-from-one-column-to-another-on-values-that-arent-equal-in-pan/43320625#comment73703859_43319855):

```
df['first name'] = df['preferred name']
print (df)
  first name preferred name
1       Dave           Dave
2       John           John
3      Sarah          Sarah
4        Liz            Liz
```

---

You can first create `boolean` mask where difference and then add new values by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
mask = df['first name'] != df['preferred name']
df.loc[mask, 'first name'] = df['preferred name']
print (df)
  first name preferred name
1       Dave           Dave
2       John           John
3      Sarah          Sarah
4        Liz            Liz
```

Another solution:

```
mask = df['first name'] != df['preferred name']
df['first name'] = df['first name'].mask(mask,df['preferred name'])
print (df)
  first name preferred name
1       Dave           Dave
2       John           John
3      Sarah          Sarah
4        Liz            Liz
```

Comment: i forgot to mention some of the entries in 'preferred name' are NaN, hence why i couldnt follow edchums method. 

but your first method seems nice and neat.

Comment: Ok, so can you change sample of data with NaN and add desired output?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean but the method you stated is what i was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 0):

slightly impatient, so i did it the 'ugly' way. queried the data for indices where names are different, and then added them on those values

```
name_index = df[df['first name'] != df['preferred name']]
df.ix[name_index,'first name'] = df.ix[name_index,'preferred name']
```